# SQL Triggers not preventing insert

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I am having trouble getting a trigger to work. What it needs to do is to prevent any customer with last name Glass from being inserted into the database. This is what I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_last_name_glass_trg
ON customer
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_LAST VARCHAR;
SET @CUSTOMER_LAST= (SELECT INSERTED.customer_last FROM INSERTED);

  IF @CUSTOMER_LAST = 'Glass'
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('Applicant Glass Denied',14,1);
  END;
END;
```

The issue is when I add customers with last name of Glass, it inserts without throwing an error. Any ideas? I can make it work in Oracle, but the same method does not work in MS SQL.

Comment: Try looking at the value you're getting in @customer_last. You're hitting some truncation issues.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. I don't see any truncation. It just says "Glass"

Comment: You want it to be Glass, but it's not

Comment: If it is truncating, then why does it say "Glass" in the table?

Comment: `INSERTED` pseudo-table can contain more than on e row, in which case your code is broken.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, true as that may be, it wasn't relevant to my issue or my scenario.

Comment: I'm sure a user with 43k+ rep is well aware about how relevant their comment is, especially when commenting several hours after the accepted answer :) In fact, Remus's point being tangential to the current issue is why he chose to comment instead of answering in the first place. It was still a perfectly valid point to raise, though, as your code *is* very brittle treating the `inserted` table like that.

Comment: It may be a valid point in a production environment, but this code was for an assignment with a very limited set of queries that needed to work. It only expects one row, not multiple rows. It was never intended to stand up to every potential query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are declaring your variable as `varchar` without any length. With variable declarations, `varchar` defaults to a length of 1 (note that in other scenarios it will have a different default length).

As a best practice, you should always specify a length on the `varchar` datatype. For more details, see [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) on the issue.

Comment: I still don't understand why the truncation doesn't hold true in my table, but that actually worked. I set the variable length to 20 and voila. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Read the article I link to. It explains.

Comment: I understand where I was confused now. The trigger was only looking for 'G', that is why the insert worked. I forgot that the INSERT doesn't have the truncation issue, just the trigger does.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of variable type is wrong as mentioned by @AMtwo.
Your code is truncating everything except the first alphabet. Meaning @CUSTOMER_LAST='G' in this example and truncating 'lass'.  Run this code in SSMS and see the value of @CUSTOMER_LAST.

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_LAST VARCHAR;
SET @CUSTOMER_LAST = 'Glass'
PRINT @CUSTOMER_LAST
```

Declare @CUSTOMER_LAST variable with same data type as the column 'customer_last'.

You might also want to look at [Using INSTEAD OF Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx).
It is always better to check these kind of things in the application.

Comment: +1 to using an INSTEAD OF trigger for something like this. Rather than inserting and rolling back, you can just not insert it. Though, I'm guessing this is a thought exercise or homework problem given how specific it is. 

Comment: The column 'customer_last' is VARCHAR, which is why the variable is VARCHAR. The table says 'Glass', not 'G'. I'm looking at it right now. Not sure where this truncation is occurring. My application doesn't show it.

Comment: @user121168 check out the link in my answer. It explains the problem pretty explicitly.

Comment: @user121168 run the code I posted  in SSMS. What value you see printed?